# How to copy from Sublime Text 3 with formatting?

Tags: formatting, sublimetext3

I have XML in Sublime Text 3 and I would like to use it as an example in Google Slides. The issue is when you copy the text you end up with plain text, I would like to keep the syntax highlighting as it makes it much easier to read. Is this possible? Is there some Sublime package I need?

Comment: indeed, ST just copies plain text to the clipboard. You may want to try https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ExportHtml and copy from the web browser instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use `CopyAsHtml` pakage. It is better than `SublimeHighlight` pakage. You can install it according to what [MS Berends](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4575331/ms-berends) said [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57871829/6286067).

`CopyAsHtml` pakage keeps sublime coloring exactly.

It will add another `copy as HTML` in your right click as you can see below.
[image]

Comment: Awesome new insight! Should become the accepted answer as far as I’m concerned.

Comment: The colors are better indeed, but I don't understand why is none of the line-breaks preserved (inserting in PPT) ?

Comment: I have this problem too and didn't find any straight solution. I just Paste in M.S. Word then Copy and Paste in PPT then change the background.

Answer (score 26):

Open the package control to install a package (Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + P):

[image]

Look for `Highlight` and click it:

[image]

Done! You can now right click some text and copy it as RTF:

[image]

Then you can paste that in Google Slides, PowerPoint, Word, Outlook, whatever you like.

Comment: Version 3.2.2 here.  Highlight doesn't appear to me.  Got any leads?

Comment: I’ll check my version tonight, but these screenshots were taken of at least v3.1. To be continued!

Comment: You're right, this is now unavailable for 3.2.2. The GitHub page of this project has also been archived in 2017. Can't find another solution, too bad...

Comment: It's in the newest ST3 again!

Comment: Worked like charm, MS Berends.